# Using .htaccess to style URL directory style

Tags: .htaccess

I have searched this question and looked around but can't seem to get this working in practice. This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /poker/(.*)/(.*)/$ /poker/?$1=$2
```

I am trying to get my page to work like this:

```
mysite.com/poker/page/home
```

But this just isn't working, I have used 3 different generators and tried typing it manually from tutorials but it is just returning a 404. Any idea's a greatly appreciated, it could be really obvious..

Thanks

Comment: So when you type `http://mysite.com/poker/?page=home` in your browser, that works?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a trailing slash in your example, yet your rule requires one. You can make the trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /poker/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /poker/?$1=$2
```

Note however, that a uri `/poker/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/` is also a match here - `a/b/c/d/e/f` will match the first subpattern and `g` will match the second one, because `(.*)` is greedy. Be more specific if you wish to match only content between slashes - e.g. `([^/]*)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried but still not working, starting to wonder if theres a server issue.. Could anybody help with that if its a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's really nothing wrong with the rules that you have if `http://mysite.com/poker/?page=home` resolves correctly. The only thing is that if this is in an htaccess file, the leading slash is removed from the URI when it's matched against in a `RewriteRule`, so you need to remove it from your regular expression (or maky it optional):

```
RewriteRule ^poker/(.+)/(.+)/?$ /poker/?$1=$2
```

And maybe make the groupings `(.+)` instead so that there is at least one character there.

Comment: RewriteRule ^poker/(.+)/(.+) /poker/?$1=$2 - I decided to try it without the trailing slash and the (.+) but it still isn't working. So confusing 'coz everywhere I have looked this seems like it should work. So I'm still left believing there must be a setting somewhere that isn't allowing this. I have full access to the server if that helps.